# Коллекции <?, array<type>> на C++/CLI

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Доброго времени суток.

Чтобы предвосхитить вопросы, что я пытаюсь реализовать, приведу идею на Python:

```py
main_dict = {"group_1": ["subgroup_1",
                         "subgroup_2"],
             "group_2": ["subgroup_3",
                         "subgroup_4"]}
additional_dict = {"subgroup_1": ["eggs",
                               "bark"],
                   "subgroup_2": ["eggs",
                               "bark"],
                   "subgroup_3": ["eggs",
                               "bark"],
                   "subgroup_4": ["eggs",
                               "bark"]}
```

Таким образом, я пытаюсь получить словарь (или коллекцию) с ключом в виде `<String^>` *(в переводе на C++)* и соответствующими значениями типа `<array<String^>>` (предположительно?).

Пытаюсь создать подобную **константную** *(мне не нужно будет изменять её в ходе программы)* коллекцию:

```
std::map < String^, array<String^> > my_map = { {"group_1", {"subgroup_1", "subgroup_2"}},
};
```

или вот так

```
std::map < String^, array<String^>^ > ...
```

Увы, компилятор выдаёт ошибку в обеих случаях.

```
Отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора ..., соответствующие списку аргументов.
```

Прошу помочь мне разобраться в ошибке или подсказать более элегантный способ осуществления данной структуры.

Comment: Нашёл некий ```System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary```, однако он не хочет позволять хранить внутри себя array<String^>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стоит смешивать нативный код с управляемым.

Если использовать только коллекции .NET Framework, то вместо `std::map` можно взять `Dictionary`.
Массив - ссылочный тип, поэтому объявъяется так: `array<String^>^` - в конце нужен `^`.

Инициализаторы коллекций в C++/CLI есть только для массива. С учётом этого код будет выглядеть так:

```
auto dict = gcnew Dictionary<String^, array<String^>^>();

dict->Add("group_1", gcnew array<String^> { "subgroup_1", "subgroup_2" });
```

---

Или использовать только неуправляемые типы:

```
std::map<std::string, std::array<std::string, 2>> my_map{ { "group_1", {"subgroup_1", "subgroup_2"} } };
```